# How is Agda inferring the implicit argument to `Vec.foldl`?

Tags: agda, lean

```
foldl : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} (B : ℕ → Set b) {m} →
        (∀ {n} → B n → A → B (suc n)) →
        B zero →
        Vec A m → B m
foldl b _⊕_ n []       = n
foldl b _⊕_ n (x ∷ xs) = foldl (λ n → b (suc n)) _⊕_ (n ⊕ x) xs
```

When translating the above function to Lean, I was shocked to find out that its true form is actually like...

```
def foldl : ∀ (P : ℕ → Type a) {n : nat}
    (f : ∀ {n}, P n → α → P (n+1)) (s : P 0)
    (l : Vec α n), P n
| P 0 f s (nil _) := s
| P (n+1) f s (cons x xs) := foldl (fun n, P (n+1)) (λ n, @f (n+1)) (@f 0 s x) xs
```

I find it really impressive that Agda is able to infer the implicit argument to `f` correctly. How is it doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
foldl : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} (B : ℕ → Set b) {m} →
        (∀ {n} → B n → A → B (suc n)) →
        B zero →
        Vec A m → B m
foldl b _⊕_ n []       = n
foldl b _⊕_ n (x ∷ xs) = foldl (λ n → b (suc n)) _⊕_ (_⊕_ {0} n x) xs
```

If I pass it 0 explicitly as in the Lean version, I get a hint as to the answer. What is going on is that Agda is doing the same thing as in the Lean version, namely wrapping the implicit arg so it is `suc`'d.

This is surprising as I thought that implicit arguments just means that Agda should provide them on its own. I did not think it would change the function when it is passed as an argument.